# Strange dependency error in installing package

Tags: debian, apt, raspberry-pi, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install an app we made in Ubuntu (with [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly)) to Raspberry Pi Raspbian. 
However, it has a dependency  **python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)** which is unmet in Raspbian although it has Python 2.8 installed. However, the app runs fine throughout Ubuntu 12.04 to 15.04.

Is this due to the mention of Ubuntu in version number?

Is there any workaround except forcing dpkg to ignore the Python version dependency issue ?(this works although makes the app a broken package)

This is the control file's dependency part (It was created by Quickly)

> Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python (>= 2.7),
>   python (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-glib-2.0,
>   gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-webkit-3.0, yelp

I don't know why there are three Python entries.

**Edit:** I made a mistake. Pi runs Python 2.7.3

This is the result of `dpkg -l python`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  python         2.7.3-4+deb7 all          interactive high-level object-ori
```

These are the results of

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dpkg -I up-clock_6.0_all.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 734750 bytes: control archive=2246 bytes.
     619 bytes,    12 lines      control              
    3762 bytes,    49 lines      md5sums              
     158 bytes,     9 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
     253 bytes,    14 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
 Package: up-clock
 Version: 6.0
 Architecture: all
 Maintainer: Archisman Panigrahi <apandada1@gmail.com>
 Installed-Size: 1562
 Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), gir1.2-glib-2.0, gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-webkit-3.0, yelp
 Section: python
 Priority: extra
 Description: A beautiful Clock, inspired by Ubuntu Touch homescreen, already on your desktop.
  Inspired by Ubuntu Touch homescreen, this clock is able to show you the
  time in a way you never seen before. The "clouds" changes colors and
  sizes automatically awhile showing you the time.



pi@raspberrypi ~ $ apt-cache policy python
    python:
      Installed: 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
      Candidate: 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
      Version table:
     *** 2.7.3-4+deb7u1 0
            500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I was not sure where to post the queston-- Ask Ubuntu, Raspbery Pi or here.

Comment: what's the output of `dpkg -I your-package.deb` and `apt-cache policy python`?

Comment: Python 2.8 doesn't exist. You must be mistaken.

Comment: Here is the best place to ask since this involves multiple distros/platforms.  I would guess it almost certainly has to do with the patch suffix in the version (`-0ubuntu2`).   You should make a separate package for Raspbian, using appropriate pre-reqs.   That may or may not be possible with "Quickly" (probably not, since it looks ubuntu specific).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three dependencies for Python are:

- `python (>= 2.7)`
- `python (<< 2.8)`
- `python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)`

The net effect is to require Python from the 2.7 series (e.g. not 2.6, not 3.x) but no older than `2.7.1-0ubuntu2`.

The first two taken together are a way of saying that you need to have Python 2.7 installed but it is allowed to be Python 2.7.anything. That is, it has to be at least 2.7 (first requirement) but less than 2.8 (second requirement). (Python 2.8 does not exist and will never exist, but it's just a way of specifying the bounds in the version ordering system used by Debian.)

The last one probably comes from an additional dependency you have during package builting. You might have a `substvar` in the source `debian/control` file (not the one that is in the package, the one that is in the source) that causes it to be autogenerated. It partially overlaps with the first requirement. In one sense it is less strict than the other dependency because of `:any` which allows the installed `python` to be from a different architecture. In another sense it is stricter, because it requires Python to be at least `2.7.1-0ubuntu2`. There must have been a bug fix in that specific version that makes 2.7.0 or even plain 2.7.1 ineligible to meet the dependency.

> although it has Python 2.8 installed.

No. Python 2.8 does not exist.

It must be the case that the version of Python you have installed doesn't meet the requirements. What does `dpkg -l python` say?

Comment: If it is because of such a bug fix, likely it is incorporated into some generic version of python > 2.7.1, but Quickly, being ubuntu-centric, is okay with their patched version (since it would have been the earliest release with this fix).  So if you can find the correspondence, then you can just use >= 2.7.3 or whatever it turns out to be.

Comment: @Celada I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

A dependency where the package name contains a colon is for [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO). The format of this dependency is `PACKAGE-NAME:ARCH` (plus an optional version specification).

The architecture part can be `any` to indicate that the dependecy can be met cross-architecture.
The [multiarch spec](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec) even gives `python:any` as an example. Most dependencies on Python require it only to run scripts, so it doesn't matter which architecture the Python executable is for; these package declare a dependency on `python:any`.

Raspbian wheezy has versions of dpkg and APT that support multiarch, but I think the feature needs to be enabled explicitly with `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`.

Of course, make sure you do have an up-to-date version of the `python` package. It can't be 2.8 since this doesn't exist. In Raspbian wheezy, it should be 2.7.3.

Comment: I was wrong the version is 2.7.3